# UITextField hide cursor after return is pressed

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uinavigationbar

I want to have an editable title for my Navigation Bar. I found this code

```
let navigationTitlelabel = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
    navigationTitlelabel.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
    navigationTitlelabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    navigationTitlelabel.textColor  = UIColor.whiteColor()
    navigationTitlelabel.text = defaultListName
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.titleView = navigationTitlelabel
    navigationTitlelabel.delegate = self
```

I have it in `viewWillAppear`. This is so I can change the title of the view controller. Then I implement these for the delegate:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    resignFirstResponder()
    return true

}
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let moc = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    if textField.text != ""{
        //save to Core Data
    return true
    }
    return false
}
```

However when I press return, the cursor still blinks. The data IS saved, and if I reload the VC the title is the new one, but I can't get out of the "editing the title mode" even if I tap another button.

How can I solve this issue?

I'm testing this on the simulator, Swift 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify textFieldShouldReturn with below code

```
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
```

Comment: Could u pls try the modified solution?